# Connector Identification please

Tags: pcb, connector, power-connector

[image: picture of unknown connector]

Can someone help me identify this connector please, I have literally no clue how to disconnect it at all.

Comment: Release the latch, if there is one and pull hard on the plastic shells. Then take a photo showing the pins. Post that along with the pin spacing dimensions.

Comment: @Transistor i pushed the latch down in the middle and pulled the two parts apart but they wont budge at all

Comment: The triangular latches on the side: try to see if these need to be pushed in to uncouple the connector.

Comment: @Syed the triangular tabs are serrated ... they are for attaching the connector into a chassis opening

Answer (score 0):

It's a ["pin and socket" connector](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=standard_rect_conn&o=pin_socket_conn).

As far as we ca see from that single picture, it is held by friction alone. Just pull the two plastic housings apart hard (not the wires).

After you unmate the two, if you want us to identify the specific one, we need the exact [pitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+pitch), and pictures of the 2 mates.

"Full Disclosure: I'm the author"